# How to print distinct element of the column

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display some data on my website. I have two columns (question and answers) in my database. I have one question and multiple answers. I want to know how can I print that. The problem I am having is that the question appears multiple time with the answers. What I want to do is have the question on the top and then all the answers.

```
 $q = "SELECT question,answer FROM questionFORM right join Answer ON              questionFORM.question_id=Answer.question_id where questionFORM.user_id=1;
    ";
    $result = $db->query($q);

<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div>
                Question: <a href="question detail page.html"><?=$row["question"]?></a>
            </div>

            <div>
                <img src="avatar.png" class="imgOne" align="left"> <span>
                    <h5>Michael Angelo</h5>



                Answer:<?=$row["answer"]?>
                </span> <span>Date:10-02-2019 Time 1:08pm</span> <span>[
                    vote: <img src="up.png" class="imgVote"> <img src="down.png"
                    class="imgVote">]
                </span>

            </div>



        </div>


        <?php
}

$db->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by`  in sql to [group](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html) it using question or

in php while looping add an if  condition something like  below

```
$question = ""
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if($question == $row["question"])
{
  dont print question
}
else
{
    print question;

$question = $row["question"];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. if i do group by it reduces the answer rows as the same as question rows.

Comment: hmm .. that condition should work . or fetch distinct question first and loop through it for each ones answers !

Comment: But the php code that you gave me works so thankyou so much